# Is it possible to check if an extension is installed on the browser (JS)?

Tags: javascript, plugins, browser

I am trying to check what extensions are installed on the client side (extensions like Adblock, User Agent Switcher). Tried `navigator.plugins` but that does not display all extensions. Is it possible to see what extensions are installed (maybe with Javascript) ?

Comment: Search for Chrome management(for Google Chrome) APIs and AddonManager(for Firefox) APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, you can't.

Unless an addon/plugin/extension specifically auths himself (usually via the User-Agent header), this is informatino the browser will not give you.

Comment: If we could detect an extension, we could change the website's behaviour in some aspects. Why would this harm anyone ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but could you point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Flosi is correct, however some of these plugins change specific behaviors. Ad-block for instance blocks some images from known ads sites and google analytics for the most part so you might trying to test for these different behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but could you point me to some documentation?

Comment: This is the best I found http://thepcspy.com/read/how_to_block_adblock/ but note that this is specific to how ad-block works today and tomorrow it might change.